# Is there a pair construction function in OCaml?

Tags: tuples, ocaml

When parsing input with `scanf`, for example with the pattern `"%d %d\n"`, I often need to write `fun x y -> x, y`.

Is there a function in the standard library to replace this expression? pair, tuple, (,), don't seem to be defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge this does not exist as part of [`Stdlib`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Stdlib.html#modules).

Having a `make2tuple` function seems straightforward: `let make2tuple a b = (a, b)`, but so does `make3tuple` and `make4tuple`, etc, etc. When is enough enough? Where do you draw the line?

This doesn't seem particular better than writing `fun a b -> (a, b)` or `fun a b c -> (a, b, c)` as needed. If they're needed often, you can create utility functions for this in your code.

Just be aware of the [value restriction](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/polymorphism.html) if you try to use partial function application with this:

```
# let mk2tuple a b = (a, b);;
val mk2tuple : 'a -> 'b -> 'a * 'b = <fun>
# let make_tuple_with_5 = mk2tuple 5;;
val make_tuple_with_5 : '_weak1 -> int * '_weak1 = <fun>
# make_tuple_with_5 2;;
- : int * int = (5, 2)
# make_tuple_with_5;;
- : int -> int * int = <fun>
# make_tuple_with_5 7.3;;
Error: This expression has type float but an expression was expected of type
         int
# mk2tuple 5 7.3;;
- : int * float = (5, 7.3)
```